# KSQL table not showing data but Stream with same structure returning data

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have created a table in KSQL, while querying it's not returning any data. Then I created a stream on the same topic with same structure and I am able to query the data.

What am I missing here. I need this as a table for joining with a stream.

```
CREATE TABLE users_table \
(registertime bigint, userid varchar, regionid varchar, gender varchar) \
WITH (value_format='json', kafka_topic='users_topic',key='userid');
```

and

```
CREATE STREAM users_stream \
(registertime bigint, userid varchar, regionid varchar, gender varchar) \
 WITH (value_format='json', kafka_topic='users_topic');
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do the messages in the topic have a key?

Comment: No, key is null. Will adding a key will fix the issue?

Comment: This issue was fixed when I added keys to the messages. Thanks Matthias and Robin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you read a topic as a `TABLE` the messages in the topic must have the key set. If the key is `null`, records will be dropped silently. A key in a KSQL `TABLE` is a primary key and `null` is no valid value for a primary key.

Furthermore, the value in the message of the key attribute, **must** be the same as the key (note, that the schema itself is define on the value of the message). For example, if you have a schema, `<A,B,C>` and you set `A` as the key, the messages in the topic must be `<key,value> == <a,<a,b,c>>`. Otherwise, you will get incorrect results.